# Access codes for authorization with Laravel

Tags: laravel, performance, authorization

1. The user visits the website of the app and enters their existing
   credentials (username and password) to access their account.
2. The authenticated user (from step 1) reviews the list of managed
   users. Choose a user to verify their posts.
3. In this scenario, we assume that the author of the publications is
   in another location, so the user in step 1 must request access
   permission.
4. The author of the publications receives a request from the user of
   step 1, upon granting the authorization, the application must
   generate a code of digits which must be entered (by the user of step 1) to be able to access the restricted information.

The following assumptions are considered:

- User A (who requests access) and user (B) who grants it are in
  different locations, but in the same building or office, so they can
  communicate with each other by phone or in person.
- The process of requesting and granting access, together with the
  generation of the access code, requires that the two users A and B be
  authenticated within the application.

In general, it is what you want to do, so I would like to know what are the correct concepts that should be used, information that should be taken into account or a library in Laravel that allows me to perform this task.

I appreciate any suggestions or information about this topic.

Thank very much. Regards.